# EDID KWorkers Overflow

Tags: linux, ssh, hdmi, edid

I'm using the IMX6 Quad from Freescale.

I'm implemented a custom Linux on it for a personal homemade project.

I've noticed a very stange behavior. Some times, randomly, I've got two KWorkers consuming between 50% and 150% of my CPU (over 400%)

I've noticed that there is a whole load of EDID informations bursting out from the Serial interface, but not on the SSH interface.

If I deactivate my HDMI driver, everything is fine, no EDID on the Serial, and no KWorker problem.

However, deactivating the HDMI is not a solution I like, because I need to display informations on my screen (and I would like to know what's going on).

Do you know how I could solve my problem ? Can I stop the EDID information from bursting out of my serial interface ?

Answer (score 0):

It happened that the problem was due to a small speck of dust, which happened to be on the connexions of the HDMI port.
This gave a small polarity problem, which causes Interruptions to be spontaneously triggered.

Hence, the HDMI connexion was lost, then came back, then was lost again, etc.

Hence, the EDID messages.

Hence, the KWorkers Overflow.